# Error upgrading application to Spring 5 on WebSphere: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype

Tags: java, spring, websphere-8

I'm trying to migrate an existing Spring 4 application to Spring 5 on WebSphere 8.5.5.14, but the application fails to start with the below error:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:250)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:196)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:387)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:415)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:491)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:537)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1450)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5572)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5698)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor165.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:666)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:91)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:488)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:322)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

I've set the classloader order to PARENT_LAST and the WAS class loader policy to SINGLE (the .ear contains only one .war module).

There seems to be a conflict between the dependencies in the application library and those provided by the web application server, but don't know how to solve it. Below are the dependencies declared in the project .pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!--Other Dependencies-->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Test Dependencies -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I scoured this and other forums but so far I haven't found a solution to this issue. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts, we managed to find a workaround for this issue. The solution that worked for us is:

1. Revert the *WAR class-loader policy* setting to "Class loader for each WAR file in application" (aka MULTIPLE) which is the standard option.
2. Exclude all transitive dependencies to javax.servlet-api. There were other internal dependencies in the pom that had different versions of servlet-api as a transitive dependency and were not matching with the server library, so we excluded them.
3. Add servlet-api as an explicit dependency with scope "test":

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
>     <version>4.0.1</version>
>     <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

After that, the application started and worked fine. I hope it helps someone who faces a similar issue.